# Google Cloud print example in java

Tags: google-cloud-print

I have to integrate Google Cloud print in my current application.
I got one example of Google Cloud print in java, but it is too old not able to login. can anyone help me.

Comment: Include that example in your question.

Comment: plz find the link below.   https://github.com/jittagornp/GoogleCloudPrint

Comment: https://github.com/jittagornp/GoogleCloudPrint :  given url is not based on Auth2 GoogleAuthnticaton, i want to use Auth2.

Comment: Please edit the link into your answer and include a complete snippet. Link-only references are frowned upon because of link rot, and comments are subject to deletion.

Comment: String request = "https://www.google.com/cloudprint" + "/search?output=json&use_cdd=true";
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        httpPost = new HttpPost(request);     
       httpPost.setHeader("X-CloudPrint-Proxy", "Google-js");
       httpPost.setHeader("Accept-Charset", "utf-8");
       Tokeninfo tokeninfo = oauth2.tokeninfo().setAccessToken(credential.getAccessToken()).execute();
       httpPost.setHeader("Authorization", "GoogleLogin auth=" + tokeninfo.toPrettyString());
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

Comment: with above code not able to login into google-cloud-print, any one can help me plz....................................................................................................<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>User credentials required</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>User credentials required</H1>
<H2>Error 403</H2>
</BODY>
</HTML>

Comment: Click the [edit button](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/42604289/edit) and put those code snippets into your question.